# How to get the latest in this case?

Tags: laravel

This is a bit hard for me as this is the first time I'm doing this kind of task and I really don't understand how to query the latest "messages".

This is what I got in my controller:

```
    public function show(Group $group)
    {
        return new GroupResource($group->load('messages.user'));
    }
```

My logic told me to do the following:

```
return new GroupResource($group->load('messages.user')->latest());
```

But I ended up getting an error... `Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.`

Comment: are you wanting to restrict the amount of records? as `latest` would just mean in descending order based on some creation timestamp (or even id)

Comment: I don't want to restrict the amount of records :)

Comment: So what's your plan then? Do you want to order the messages attached to the group by their timestamp? You'll need to be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Yes, by their timestamp, latest to oldest.

Comment: `latest('updated_at');` try this.  `updated_at` is the field

Comment: @STA I'm getting an empty array with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add constraints to a relationship query like this:

```
return new GroupResource(
    $group->load([
      'messages' => function ($query) {
          return $query->latest();
      },
      'messages.user'
    ])
);
```

See [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) in the docs for reference.

Comment: Should've been fixed.

Comment: Might be fixed now.

Comment: Yup, that was right. This is the correct answer. I'm grateful! :)